# Extract dimensions from a pandas column excluding year

Tags: pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a Sku master description and I want to extract **just dimensional numbers** (volume / weight related) and exclude all other charactor & figure combinations that are not relevant such as "year" , "N5", "number of products bought"

This is my code so far

```
def find_number(text):
    num = re.findall(r'[^N\d+](\d+)(g|ml|mm|m|cm|dm)?',text)
    return num


df['number']=df['SKU Master Description'].apply(lambda x: find_number(x))
```

| SKU Master Description | numbers |
| --- | --- |
| LA MOUSSE 150ml | 150ml |
| BLEU DE CHANEL PARFUM SPRAY 100ml / PARFUM POUR HOMME | 100ml |
| N5 EAU DE PARFUM SPRAY 100ml | 100ml |
| FOLD.MEDIUM S.BLACK GIFT BOX 2016 / FOLDABLE/SIZE 222.2x222.2x100.3mm | 222.2x222.2x100.3mm |
| BLACK RIBBON 15mm ROLL 100m | 15mm , 100m |
| 12 PAPER BAGS SMALL SIZE / 140x50x120mm | 140x50x120mm |
|  |  |

Answer (score 2):

The following regex matches your targeted parts and units.

```
\b\d[\dx.]*(?:ml|[cdm]?m)\b
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/biblLN/2)

- `\b` matches a [word boundary](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html)
- `\d` is a [short](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for *digit*
- `(?:` [non capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) `)` with [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)
- `[` [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `]` matches one character from the listed
- `*` [repeats](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) *any amount* of times, `?` *zero or one* ([optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html))

---

The pattern above is not highly accurate but should get the job done.
More specific: [`\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:x\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*(?:ml|[cdm]?m)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/biblLN/3)